# Is there any way I can undo a published merge in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch

I have pushed a merge changeset, but I found afterwards that there are some improperly resolved conflicts in the merge.

Is there any way to undo the merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have pushed the changeset, it is available to everyone else and you cannot change it. If you are the only user of the central repository, you can use [MQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) and strip the offensive merge and redo it correctly. If there are other people using the central repository, your only option would be to push a changeset that fixes the problems that you were unable to fix during your merge.

Comment: Thanks smooth reggae. How about I strip the changeset in the central repository and others pull? Would this cause troubles?

Comment: If this is the most recent changeset and nobody else has pulled the latest from the server, stripping the changeset will work for you. Anyone who has already pulled this change in will have to abandon their local clone and clone afresh; they will be unable to pull, because strip will have altered the history of the repository as far as their local clone is concerned.

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for, could you accept it? :)